# How to view all the videos I have ever liked on YouTube when the number is very big?

Tags: youtube

When I go to the "Likes" section of the YouTube video manager under my account I can only see 2 pages of the likes list and the last video in the list is for sure far not the first video I've ever liked. I am actively using YouTube for years, clicking "like" to be able to revisit the video, but now I can only see a small part of all I've liked.

I believe that I have once opened the full list but I can't remember how did I do that.

Do you happen to know the way?

If there is no way to do this through the YouTube UI, solutions involving API usage are also welcome. I just don't want to lose the list.

Comment: Even though it shows the total number of liked videos, the list still only has 200 items in it. I have 1/5000 shown. I have to start the last one in the list to make it load the next set of 100 videos. Now I am wondering if there is a 5,000 limit. I thought likes were changed to unlimited.

Comment: YouTube seems to have changed their UI, making old answers unhelpful. I'm able to directly access my Liked Videos playlist via this URL:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=LL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that YouTube is limiting every playlist to 200 entries. A solution I came across is to create a new playlist, put the 200 displayed entries from your liked list inside, and delete them from the liked list. The liked list is then not empty, but contains 200 previously liked videos. Proceed until you have all liked videos in playlists.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see all of them go to:

> http://www.youtube.com/user/YOURYOUTUBENAME/videos?view=15&flow=grid

Instead of `YOURYOUTUBENAME` type your actual YouTube username.
*One way to find your username is to go to `your channel` and then `about` then you can find it in the URL after the `https://www.youtube.com/user/` and before the `/about?view_as=subscriber`. Keep  in mind that this might change*.

Hope it helps. Helped me :)

Comment: I feel like this isn't complete, since I'm missing videos that are in a series, that I'm sure I would have liked, but it definitely gives more than the 200 shown by default. Good find.

Comment: @JamesSkemp did you find proof of this?

Comment: Proof of which part?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Youtube has silently removed the 200 video cap for playlists

The most recent [playlist related update](http://youtube-global.blogspot.com/2014/02/more-love-for-playlists-and-new-look.html) to the [Official Youtube Blog](http://youtube-global.blogspot.com/) doesn't have any specific info.

And the [Playlist v2.0 API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists) and the [Playlist v3.0 API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists) both still note that:

> A playlist can contain up to 200 videos

*Despite all that*, the restriction seems to have been silently removed, as identified by the Yahoo Answers question [Have youtube increased the 200 video limit on their playlists?](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140316043753AA3112Y) and the Reddit post [Playlist Limit increased from 200?](http://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/2f816l/)

Anecdotally, you can browse [YouTube Nation](https://www.youtube.com/user/youtubenation/playlists?flow=list&sort=dd&view=1) which aggregates playlists on youtube and has several over the previous 200 video limit.

If you go to https://www.youtube.com/my_liked_videos there is still a size restriction, but just click play all and it will load up the whole playlist in the autoplay window.  If you want to view it in it's entirety, just click on the playlist name in the autoplay to get taken to [https://www.youtube.com/user/*{user_name}*/playlists](https://www.youtube.com/user/user_name/playlists)

[image: Playlist]

Here's [another workaround if it's still not working](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/40288/youtube-find-all-the-liked-videos/)

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: unbelievable but this is already not up to date only a few months later...

Here's an answer for 2020:

> [youtube.com/my_liked_videos](https://www.youtube.com/my_liked_videos).

It seems like some of the stuff here is outdated but I must say @jopisa's answer is great it's most likely a feature which has been removed from the YouTube GUI but not deactivated so you can still reach it by using the right URL. Using the URL provided in @jopisa's answer will filter the videos you liked but no longer have access to them (they were removed from YouTube or became private) and shows them *not* in a playlist.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your own youtube channel and go to the "Likes" section. It should show all of it.

Comment: That's considered a oneliner here on web applications. Please give some additional information. The FAQ is good reading. Welcome to Web Applications.

Comment: I think that's what I did and it doesn't  show _all_, just the last ~200.

Comment: It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube used to have a feature that placed a checkmark next to playlists which already contained the  video in question. This was great if you had several playlists (each playlist holds 200 videos) because it notified told you which playlist the video was located in, you could keep track of all your playlisted-videos without worrying about placing the same video in multiple playlists. But I think YouTube or Google changed the system so that the checkmark was mostly removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I view all my liked videos on YouTube:

Go to your "Liked Videos" section and click **play** on one of the videos. Next to the video playing is a playlist of your liked videos (in black color). To the top of this playlist is the title **Liked Videos** Just click that and that's it. At the bottom of the new page there is "Load more" button and it loads 100 videos every time it's clicked so you can view all your liked videos!

Take care! :)