# Search through YouTube liked videos

Tags: youtube

I am trying to find one song but I don't want to scroll through all videos that I liked and there is a good chance I will miss the video I'm searching for!

Is there a way to search through YouTube videos that I liked?

Comment: related http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40732/how-to-view-all-the-videos-i-have-ever-liked-on-youtube-when-the-number-is-very

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following links to retrieve XML details from the YouTube API.

Only 50 results can be returned per-query, so you may need to do several requests.

Just replace CHANNELID with your YouTube Channel ID.

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/CHANNELID/favorites?start-index=1&max-results=50

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/CHANNELID/favorites?start-index=51&max-results=50

Comment: I get "Not allowed." message...

Comment: It sounds like your favorites "Playlist" is not Public. You can temporarily set this list to Public in 'Playlist Settings' at https://www.youtube.com/my_favorites

Comment: Its not my favorites videos, i asked about my liked videos...

Comment: Apologies. Your 'Liked Videos' are a playlist, so you'll need to use the playlistItems collection - see https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list

Comment: The service is "No longer available".

Answer (score 0):

I developed an extension if someone still needs one. It also show some simple stats:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-plas-playlist-sea/lcimgnlononijobbcfdejigpaobhcokk

Answer (score -4):

Login to youtube, on the left navigation menus, click Liked Videos

Comment: The OP has already said that this is not an option.